# What is the mother-site for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

I need a website that has many Raspberry Pi projects! In particular for electrical projects for kids, especially projects that will impress the kids. 
I will be mainly working with the GPIO pins.

Answer (score 1):

It must be raspberrypi.org

Have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/physical-computing/ for GPIO and https://www.raspberrypi.org/community/

Answer (score 1):

The official website is https://www.raspberrypi.org/

I really like Adafruit for kits and projects here: https://learn.adafruit.com/

Instuctables also has a lot of projects: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Projects/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, [make](http://makezine.com) has the funnest electronics projects for kids.